# Is LINQ-to-Object is a LINQ provider?

Tags: linq, linq-to-objects, linq-query-syntax

I have some confusion that, In Linq-to-Object we work in-memory data to execute LINQ query that is process by c# language.

When i write a Linq query that is execute base on in-memory data why we use provider (LINQ-to-Object)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, **Linq to Object** IS NOT A PROVIDER and it doesn't have to relay on any other intermediate provider to run query(linq to object).

To understand it more clearly, we have to understand what provider actually is. Provider is basically the implementation that implements *IQueryProvider* and *IQueryable* interface and this mainly translates your linq query to *SOMETHING* that your provider understands. For example, when you go for **LINQ to SQL** queries your queries converted/translated into SQL, its get translated into SQL because your provider (in this case) only understands SQL.

When you run query against In-Memory collection of data, C# don't have to translate your linq query to other query.

As @Stilgar mention "*Providers are used when the source is IQueryable*". When you are working against In-Memory data, your source is basically IEnumerable.

Answer (score 2):

LINQ to Objects is not a LINQ provider. It is an implementation of the LINQ API on IEnumerable. The LINQ API can be implemented on practically any type as long as you name your methods properly and accept the proper arguments. That being said there is something very close to a LINQ provider related to LINQ to Objects. Providers are used when the source is IQueryable and the compiler produces an expression tree. An expression tree can be compiled to a delegate so the Compile method acts as something very similar to a LINQ provider.

Also note that in practice "LINQ Provider" is often used to indicate simply an implementation of the LINQ API. It is kind of similar to how "argument" and "parameter" are used interchangeably despite the small difference.